# sql select into

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the below code in test.sql file.  When there is a record in test_summary table everything works fine.  But when there is no record inside the table it fails.  I want it to continue to print the dbms_output message and process when there is no record. How can I do that?

```
declare

    total_var      number(20,2) := 0.0;
    nl_var          number(20,2) := 0.0;

begin

    select col1,col2
    into total_var,nl_var
    from testsch.test_summary;

    dbms_output.put_LINE('');
    dbms_output.put_LINE('testing1' || total_var);
    dbms_output.put_LINE('testing2' || nl_var);

end;
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd add a simple NO_DATA_FOUND exception handler.

```
declare
    total_var      number(20,2) := 0.0;
    nl_var          number(20,2) := 0.0;
begin
    begin
      select col1,col2
      into total_var,nl_var
      from testsch.test_summary;
    exception
      when no_data_found then null;
    end;
    dbms_output.put_LINE('');
    dbms_output.put_LINE('testing1' || total_var);
    dbms_output.put_LINE('testing2' || nl_var);
end;
```

Comment: Ok, but you must handle TOO_MANY_ROWS exception too, please add it to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Gary's perfectly valid answer, you can also avoid the error altogether by using an explicit cursor:

```
declare
    total_var      number(20,2) := 0.0;
    nl_var          number(20,2) := 0.0;
    cursor cur_test_summary is
      select col1,col2
      from testsch.test_summary;
begin
    open cur_test_summary;
    fetch cur_test_summary into total_var, nl_var;
    close cur_test_summary;
    dbms_output.put_LINE('');
    dbms_output.put_LINE('testing1' || total_var);
    dbms_output.put_LINE('testing2' || nl_var);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer variant with exception (see answer from @Gary), but there are another common variant, wich dials with problem:

```
declare

    total_var      number(20,2) := 0.0;
    nl_var          number(20,2) := 0.0;

begin

    select max(col1) , max(col2)
    into total_var,nl_var
    from testsch.test_summary;

    dbms_output.put_LINE('');
    dbms_output.put_LINE('testing1' || total_var);
    dbms_output.put_LINE('testing2' || nl_var);

end;
```

Your can use min() - don't matter. 
If no data found you got null values in variables

Answer (score 0):

Could do it all in one go.  Avoid the not found and too many rows I believe.

```
select col1,col2 into total_var,nl_var
from
(
    select col1,col2 from 
    (
      select col1,col2
      from testsch.test_summary
      UNION ALL
      select null,null from dual
    ) t1 order by col1
) where rownum = 1
```